# Inserting radio button value into SQL

Tags: php, sql, forms, radio-button

Working out a simple star ratings script. Data not inserting into SQL. I am passing a 'id' in  the url from the form action to coincide with the rating. I'm using GET to retreive that value. I'm using POST to insert the radio button value. I've tested and the url is passing the id. The script runs to completion. SQL is connecting.

index.html

```
    <form method="POST" action="rating.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
      <fieldset class="rating">
          <legend>. . .</legend>
              <input type="radio" id="star3" name="starno" value="3" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
                  <label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
              <input type="radio" id="star2" name="starno" value="2" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
                  <label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
              <input type="radio" id="star1" name="starno" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
                  <label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

ratings.php

```
    <?php
    isset($_GET['id']);
    $con=mysqli_connect ("","","","");
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date) VALUES ('$_GET[id]','$_POST[starno]',now())");
    mysqli_close($con);
    header('Location: http://www.website.com/'); 
    ?>
```

SQL

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratings` 
    (
      `ratingid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `storyidr` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
      `rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `entry_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ratingid`),
    UNIQUE KEY `ratingid` (`ratingid`)
    ) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='rating for stories' AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Comment: You never actually run the query, and you should probably put a space between `)` and `VALUES`.

Comment: you have multiple checkbox with the same name so on submit it will post the last element no matter which one u check. So u can use name as an array name="rating[]" so that the data comes in array and catch the value in PHP.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty : actually, it is a group of radio buttons and only one of them will be selected at a time, so no array name is needed as only one value can be active at any time.

Comment: You're wonderfully open to SQL Injection; you might want to take care of that to avoid getting hacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting:

```
$storyidr = $_POST['id'];
```

but it is actually passed in the URL. therefore you need to use:

```
$storyidr = $_GET['id'];
```

The form 'method' does not need to be changed.

I have looked at the generated sql and it now contains all the input.

Comment: Posted new code (shorter), still not working.I made your suggested changes (i think). Current code shorter with some renamed variablesscript runs but no data gets into SQL. The URL is passing the id. Did I not follow your instructions correctly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I did not actually try to correct all your code. I did not run your code to see if it worked properly or not. I did run it and looked at the generated SQL to ensure that the input you expected was in there. I will produce a tested version of your code that will at least run round and insert records.

Comment: Ryan I just got it. I'm posting above. . .thank you very much and hope I didn't waste any of your time in the last 15 min, just fixed it now. Added space before VALUES and used ('$_GET[id]','$_POST[starno]',now())

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you are using a "form method="post"" , change to get.

Your script is looking for a GET but you are using POST, your script doesn't insert into the db unless the GET is and id, which it never will be with a POST